# complex analysis - Non existence of holomorphic functions on unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

D be an open unit disc in complex plane. f:D$\to C$ is a non constant holomorphic function. Which of the following conditions can possibly be satisfied by f

1. f($\frac 1n$)=f($\frac {-1}n$)= $\frac 1{n^2}$ for all n $\in$ N
2. f($\frac 1n$)=f($\frac {-1}n$)= $\frac 1{2n+1}$ for all n $\in$ N
3. |f($\frac 1n$)|< $\ 2^{-n}$ for all n $\in$ N
4. $\frac 1{\sqrt n}$<|f($\frac 1n$)|< $\frac 2{\sqrt n}$ for all n $\in$ N

I know that the answer is option 1. f(z)=$\ z^2$ satisfies the given conditions. I have also proved that the 2nd option is not true by using uniqueness theorem. But I am not being able to prove that option 3 and option 4 cannot be satisfied by f. I think maximum modulus principle can be used to prove this. But I have no clue how to apply it. Please give some hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3) and 4) we get $f(0)=0$ by continuity. Since $f$ is non-constant it has a zero of some finite order at $0$. Thus $f(z)=g(z)z^{N}$ in some neighborhood of $0$ where $g$ is analytic, $g(0) \neq 0$ and $N$ is a positive integer.

In 3) this gives $\frac C {n^{N}} <\frac 1  {2^n}$ for some $C>0$ and $n$ sufficienlty large. This is a contradiction because $2^{n} \to \infty$ faster than  any power of $n$.

The argument for 4) is also along the same lines and I will leave this to you. (Let me know if you need details).